# Global "npm ERR! peer dep missing" can this be fixed?

Tags: npm, package, global, dependency-management, npm-package

Looking for a clear direct answer.

I have installed a global  [Package A ] 
 
*Let's say aws-amplify, e.g. @aws-amplify.*

[ Package A ] has [ Package B ] that wants [ Package C ]. 
 
*e.g. aws-amplify has inquirer-autocomplete-prompt that wants inquirer*

`npm ERR! peer dep missing: inquirer@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0, required by inquirer-autocomplete-prompt@1.0.2`

Looking for a clear and direct answer, 
 
Can this be fixed or addressed in the global node packages?

Comment: As a footnote, I'm new to npm packages and wanted to cleanup as many errors I come across so I can better know what's going wrong in my projects.

Comment: I've already tried global-installing acceptable package versions, but peer-dependency-missing error still occurs.

Comment: @user11744573 Dependencies missing is an issue for me, yes.